# Upload to Swift Pseudo folders using duplicity

Tags: python, openstack-swift, duplicity

I'm trying to use duplicity to backup files to a Swift Object Storage service offered by RunAbove. The name of the container is "backup" and it has a pseudo folder named "web" inside which I want to place backups.

Duplicity version: 0.6.24
Python version: 2.7.3
python-keystoneclient 1.0.0
python-swiftclient 2.3.1

After setting the necessary environment variables I have tried the following commands:

```
duplicity --no-encryption /var/www swift://backup/web/
```

Returns the following error:

```
Listing of 'backup/web/' failed (attempt 1): JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Then I tried:

```
duplicity --no-encryption --file-prefix web/ /var/www swift://backup
```

Which returns python errors:

```
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: none
No signatures found, switching to full backup.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1509, in <module>
with_tempdir(main)
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1503, in with_tempdir
fn()
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1352, in main
do_backup(action)
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1478, in do_backup
full_backup(col_stats)
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 545, in full_backup
globals.backend)
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 420, in write_multivol
sig_outfp.to_partial()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_temp.py", line 168, in to_partial
self.tdp.rename(self.dirpath.append(self.partname))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 612, in rename
os.rename(self.name, new_path.name)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How do I backup files to a pseudo folder in OpenStack Swift using duplicity?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in duplicity v0.7.08 (see http://duplicity.nongnu.org/CHANGELOG)

> - Merged in lp:~ghoz/duplicity/swift-prefix
>
>   - adds the abiliy to use path in the swift backend, in order to have multiple
>       backups to the same container neatly organized.

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.